# Cut partially a fundamental polygon is valid?

Tags: surfaces

We know that cut/glue are operations in fundamental polygons in order to obtain surfaces.

Now, I wonder if you cut partially the fundamental polygon of a torus, with label word $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, square since one of his vertex until (aproximately) its center.

So you get the middle of a diagonal. This new edge with label $c$, so the new label word is $aba^{-1}cc^{-1}b^{-1}$.

Now, can you separate this new edge to "open" the square until get a hexagon?

Thanks

Comment: Sure, but you won’t obtain a new surface...

Comment: Thanks! That's what I wanted to know!